# Select data from the ends of a many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a database of posts, each of which have tags. These tables are named `Posts` and `Tags` respectively. I also have a third table, called `Posts_Tags` which maintains a many-to-many relationship between these two tables.

In order to do this, both my posts and my tags tables have an `id` column. My `Posts_Tags` table, therefore, has both a `postid` and `tagid` column to store the mappings.

I am querying, for example, all posts with the word "class" in the title. I can do this easily with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE title LIKE '%{class}%'
```

However, now I want to query all posts which not only have "class" in the title, but are also tagged with the "Java" tag. I could do this in two separate queries, where I first get the id of the Java tag:

```
SELECT id FROM Tags WHERE name='Java'
```

Then I could plug that into my first query, like this:

```
SELECT     Posts.* 
FROM       Posts 
INNER JOIN Posts_Tags 
        ON Posts.id=Posts_Tags.postid 
WHERE      Posts_Tags.tagid='$java_tag_id' 
           AND title LIKE '%{class}%'
```

However, I know I can do this in a single query, I just don't know how. I still have to think a lot about joins when doing just one, and doing multiple joins in the same query makes my head spin. How should I structure my query to perform this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    SELECT p.* 
      FROM Posts p 
      JOIN Posts_Tags pt
        ON pt.postid = p.id
      JOIN tags t
        ON t.id = pt.tagid
     WHERE t.tag='java'
       AND p.title LIKE '%{class}%';
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I think I was overthinking this a little, heh. Anyway, this works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    p.*
FROM posts as p 
INNER JOIN Posts_Tags pt ON pt.post_id = p.id
INNER JOIN  Tags as t ON pt.tags_id = t.id
WHERE   t.tag='java'
AND p.title LIKE '%keyword%';
```